# Cannot create Access Point on Ubuntu 14.04 [Wireless card BCM4352]

Tags: 14.04, wireless, wireless-access-point

I am unable to create wireless access point on my Ubuntu 14.04. I have BCM4352 wireless card.

on running command `iw list` , I find that AP is not listed on supported  interface modes.

How can I get supported drivers to make AP? What should I do?

[image]